# Simple hide/show div+js : how to start hidden?

Tags: javascript

I have a Hide/show div with a button and javascript code. I want to start it hidden (and not show).

can you help me ?

HTML
Click Me

```
<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

this is were i have found the code : [hide/show](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)

Comment: You could add `style="display:none;"` to the `div`. That way when the page is loaded initially it'll be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put onload in body

```
 <body onload="myFunction()">
```